# How to Match a Pattern within Another Match in Vim Syntax file

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a custom config that involves the following syntax:

- `key=value`
- `$(var)` represents a variable

The `$(var)` part can appear in both `key` and `value`, i.e. `message="hello $(FirsName) $(LastName)"`. The `value` part must be surrounded by double quote `"` if it contains space characters.

I want to match `key`, `value` and `$(var)` and highlight them separately in vim.

Here is what in my vim syntax file:

```
syn match configValue "\(\S\+=\)\@<=\"[^\"]*\"\|\(\S\+=\)\@<=\S\+"
syn match configKey "^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_.]\+\(\s*=\)\@="
syn match configVar "\$(.*)"
```

The code successfully matches `configValue` and `configKey`, but not `configVar` if it is within `key=value`. This is ruled by the syntax match priority (`h:syn-priority`):

1. When multiple Match or Region items start in the same position, the item
   defined last has priority.
2. A Keyword has priority over Match and Region items.
3. An item that starts in an earlier position has priority over items that
   start in later positions.

Rule 3 gives the other two matches higher priority than that of `configVar`.

My problem is that, how to match the three patterns separately, with `configVar` having the highest priority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have `configVar` match inside `configValue`, you have to **contain** it; this is done via the `contained` (leave this off if the var can also match anywhere, not just inside key=value) and `contains=...` attributes:

```
syn match configValue "\(\S\+=\)\@<=\"[^\"]*\"\|\(\S\+=\)\@<=\S\+" contains=configVar
syn match configVar "\$([^)]*)" contained
```

Note that I've changed the pattern for `configVar` to avoid matching `$(foo) and $(bar)` as *one* element.

---

You said that `configVar` can also appear in `configKey`, but for that, the range of allowed characters needs to include `$()`, too. Then, the containment works just as well:

```
syn match configKey "^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_.$()]\+\(\s*=\)\@=" contains=configVar
```

Comment: It works. Didn't know that `match` can also have `contains`. Cool.

Comment: It can do a lot of cool things like that. I recommend going through `:help syntax` (`:help :syn-arguments` would also make a decent starting point) for more on `match` etc. :)